# How can I add CKRecords to an array before using that array to fill cells in a UITableView in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, swift

I have been trying to use a fetchRecords function to fill an array of CKRecords to fill a UITableView of cells. When I run the app, the UITableView calls the numberOfRowsInSection function before the fetchRecords function.

```
func fetchRecords(){
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Counter", predicate: predicate)

    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record : CKRecord!) in

        self.objects.append(record)
        println("recordFetchedBlock: \(record)")
    }

    cloudKitHelper.privateDB.addOperation(queryOperation)

    /*
    cloudKitHelper.privateDB.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: {(results, error) ->Void in
        if error != nil{
            println(error)
        }
        else {
            println(results)

            for result in results{
                self.objects.append(result as! CKRecord)
                println(self.objects[0].valueForKey("Title"))
                println(self.objects[0].valueForKey("Count"))
            }
        }
    })*/
}
```

I have tried using both addOperation and performQuery to obtain the records. Both seem to work properly, they just obtain the records after the UITableView has already run the numberOfRowsInSection method, which returns objects.count

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchRecords()
```

As you can see, fetchRecords() is the first thing called in viewDidLoad() after the super call.

I'm trying to figure out how to load the objects array with the CKRecords before the UITableView loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update UI elements on the main dispatch thread.  The `recordFetchedBlock` is going to be called multiple times - presumably, each time, as records become available, you'll want to update your table view.  Try this:

```
queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record : CKRecord!) in
  println("recordFetchedBlock: \(record)")
  dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.objects.append(record)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Comment: that did it. Thank you! Im confused, however, on what the dispatch_async function does

Comment: The second argument to `dispatch_async()` is a 'thunk' - a closure of no arguments and no return - the first argument is a queue.  The behavior is to schedule the thunk on the queue for later execution on some thread.